# How to use InverseKinematics to solve IK on MultibodyPlant?

Tags: c++, drake

I was trying to use InverseKinematics to solve the IK for a MultibodyPlant. I was trying to add some position constraints to it and then do the solver.

```
drake::multibody::InverseKinematics kinsol(plant);
auto world = plant.world_frame();
Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3d> p_BQ;
Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3d> p_AQ_lower;
Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3d> p_AQ_upper;

auto COM = plant.GetFrameByName("hip_mass");
p_BQ << ...
p_AQ_lower << ...
p_AQ_upper << ...
auto pos1 = kinsol.AddPositionConstraint(COM, p_BQ, world, p_AQ_lower, p_AQ_upper);

drake::solvers::MathematicalProgramResult result = drake::solvers::Solve(kinsol.prog());
auto result_vec = result.GetSolution();
```

But the compiler gives the errors

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'drake::multibody::BodyFrame<double>'
      auto world = plant.world_frame();
           ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/multibody/tree/_virtual_includes/multibody_tree_core/drake/multibody/tree/body.h:68:35: note: 'BodyFrame' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  DRAKE_NO_COPY_NO_MOVE_NO_ASSIGN(BodyFrame)


error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3d>' (aka 'Ref<const Matrix<double, 3, 1> >')
      Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3d> p_BQ;

error: variable type 'drake::multibody::Frame<double>' is an abstract class
      auto COM = plant.GetFrameByName("hip_mass");
```

I am not sure if I used the InverseKinematics correctly. Does anyone have solutions for this? Or maybe other ways to do the IK for RigidbodyTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change that line `auto world = plant.world_frame()` to

```
const auto& world = plant.world_frame();
```

When you use `auto`, the compiler probably tries to infer the type as `BodyFrame`, but we don't have a copy constructor for `BodyFrame`. If you change it to `const auto&`, the type of `world` is `const BodyFrame&`, constructing this const reference doesn't need to call the copy constructor.

Similarly for the line `auto COM = plant.GetFrameByName("hip_mass");`, this line should be changed to

```
const auto& COM = plant.GetFrameByName("hip_mass");
```

BTW, the hip mass frame is very likely not exactly where the center of mass (COM) is.

And when you call `Solve(kinsol.prog())`, I would suggest to give it an initial guess, otherwise Drake will use a zero vector as the default initial guess. Very likely the robot is in a singular configuration with zero vector (some rows of your Jacobian become zero). That is not a good initial start for many gradient-based nonlinear optimization solvers. I would recommend to change it to

```
const Eigen::VectorXd q_guess = Eigen::VectorXd::Constant(plant.num_positions(), 0.1);
const auto result = Solve(kinsol.prog(), q_guess);
```

that you use a non-zero vector `q_guess` as the initial guess.